# how to get data from a datagridview and insert into database without using databinding?

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset

i ve a datagrid and wen a button s clicked i want the values from the datadrid to the database..

without databind to dataset/datatable..

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should databind to something.

Use a List<> or better BindingList<> of a simple class that has properties for each column in your Db.